# How to sort using data-categories attribute

Tags: html, sorting, filter, filtering, portfolio

I came across a great sorting portfolio that I'm trying to modify to fit my needs, but I can't figure out how to sort the list via the URL. As it stands right now, the default is to automatically load "All" projects, then sort the list using the data-categories attributes based on the chosen category. That works great for the home page, but where my problem comes in is that I'd like to include this same menu on an interior project page, and when a specific category is clicked, have it link back to the home page, sorting to the appropriate category.

Here's my specific example of a project page with the non working menu: http://staging.jtgurzi.com/single-project.php

And here is the main page with all the projects: http://staging.jtgurzi.com/

From any project page like above example, I'd like to be able to click a category(e.g. Feature Film) and have it link back to where all the projects are listed, filtering to the aforementioned "Feature Film" category(almost like an anchor tag in a sense). Since the sort generates the link automatically, I can't call it(or figure out how to) via href. I've tried /index.php&data-categories=feature, but no dice.

Long story short, click category link within project page --> linked back to index page --> thumbnails are filtered to the correct category automatically.

Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
-Erik

Comment: I'm not too familiar with PHP but I don't think this question is completely clear. One important tenement is posting your attempt at the problem. Consider adding that to your question since it adds context and will make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Isotope hash history with bbq plugin was exactly what I was looking for:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html